# Cannot create unknown type clr-namespace: ONLY on one "TFS build agent"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-2012

Something strange happened to one of our TFS Build servers

This is the scenario:

I have one Controller and two Build servers with two agents each one

- If I queue any build forcing it to run on my Build server 01, the build success
- If I queue the same build on my Build server 02, the build fails

The error is the following:

> Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly}MyClassName'.

This is a custom MSBuild assembly and it targets the .Net Framework 4.5, this is checked in on the TFS control version, the controller is pointing to the correct path on TFS.

The DLL has not being updated in like 6 months

I do not understand why this is happening. And more disconcerting is the fact that this build server was working correctly yesterday, and anyone in the team has done anything to the server, they do not even have access.

I think the error is occurring before executing the build workflow, **this would mean that for some reason the build template cannot be loaded** which makes sense since the type cannot be resolved

Things that I have done so far:

- Yesterday morning the build server 02 was running smoothly
- I'm sure i"m using the same build running it on both build servers. This makes me think that there is no problems with the build template
- I'm sure any build fails on my build server 02 with the same error
- All the builds that I have tested run on 01 without issues
- Both build servers are enable, available and accessible on the network
- Both build servers have been configured with the domain account that is used to run the builds
- Both servers have access to the working folders and the TFS user has access to those servers
- The domain account belongs to the Administrators group on both build servers
- I double checked and these assemblies are not in the GAC on both build servers (I would not like to put them on the GAC, and again, my build server 01 is working correctly without the need to put the DLL's on the GAC)
- I compared the Windows Update history, and both servers were updated on the same date like 3 months ago

This is what I found

**On my build server 01**, I found that the custom build DLL's used to build were in the correct locations:

```
C:\Users\MyTFSServiceAccount\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildAgent\24\Assemblies

C:\Users\MyTFSServiceAccount\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildAgent\25\Assemblies
```

The previous paths had all the assemblies needed

**On my build server 02**, the folder was containing only one DLL, for some reasons the DLL's are not being copied, I checked the folder permissions and everything looks good, the tfsservice account has permissions to the folders and it is an administrator on the box

These are the paths on my build server 02

```
C:\Users\MyTFSServiceAccount\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildAgent\22\Assemblies

C:\Users\MyTFSServiceAccount\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildAgent\23\Assemblies
```

Well, I thought that copying the DLL's manually would solve the problem temporally....I was wrong =( I copied the DLL's but I'm receiving the same error

Could you guys please point me to the right direction?

Comment: If such a thing happens out of the blue, first thing I double check are things like MS Update. Maybe this ran on build server 02 yesterday but not on 01?

Comment: I will update the question, I just checked the Windows updates logs and they are identical, the last time an update was installed was like 3 months ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jaja

This is why I hate TFS and this is why I love being a Software Engineer

After spending almost all day on this issue and validating everything that crossed to my mind,  at the end, it seems that the simplest approach always work...

I just restarted the TFS Services and magically everything started working again....